# how to remove Duplicate IP in PHP

Tags: php, file-io

I wrote the code that save the ip of client into logs.txt but i want to remove the additional ip from the logs.txt . what am i going to do ?

```
$at = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$log = fopen("logs.txt", "a"); 
fwrite($log, $at ."\n"); 
fclose($log);
```

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

try following command

sort file | uniq > file.new

Answer (score 1):

Method #1

```
$at = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$log = file_get_contents("logs.txt");
$log = trim($log); // removes leading/trailing blank lines
$log = explode("\n", $log);
$log[] = $at;
$log = array_unique($log);
$log = implode("\n", $log);
file_put_contents("logs.txt", $log);
```

Method #2

```
$at = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$log = file_get_contents("logs.txt");
$temp = explode("\n", $log);
if(in_array($at, $temp) == false) {
    file_put_contents("logs.txt", $log . $at . "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Salman's way because it works both in Windows or Linux boxes.

However, consider using a database such as [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) that saves all the data in a single file. So, you will be able to query your data in a more flexible way.

Answer (score 0):

Using linux:

```
sort logs.txt | uniq
```

Btw usually the ip will be logged in the webservers access log.